# Installing PostGIS on PostgreSQL 12

Tags: postgis, postgresql, installation

I installed PostgreSQL 12 using Windows Installer. After the installation, there´s no option to install postgis extension. I tried to add postgis support in a database using CREATING EXTENSION and I got an error message about postgis.control missing file.

How can I proceed to use PostGIS features in PostgreSQL 12?

Comment: Checking [the PostGIS website](https://postgis.net/windows_downloads/), I don't see any mention of it working on Postgres 12. If you could use 11 instead, that site should give you all the information and links needed to install it.

Comment: Yes, you´re right. On the other hand, there´s no mention that it doesn´t. :)

Comment: PostGIS 3 is compatible with Postgres 12 http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/

Comment: PostGIS 3 is imminent https://twitter.com/pwramsey/status/1180160479584378880

Comment: Which platform/os do you use? For windows there is a batch script for example.

Answer (score 4):

I installed it yesterday, you could use the application Stack Builder. Here you have some screenshots.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a new PostGIS release out today (PostGIS 3.0.0rc1) that works with PostgreSQL 9.5-12 and GEOS >= 3.6: http://postgis.net/2019/10/08/postgis-3.0.0rc1/

(Admittedly I have not yet succeeded in adding it to my own PostgreSQL 12 database on Windows 10, which is how I landed here on this thread.)